# Intellij IDEA: Git plugin not working anymore with error "the git process exited with the code 139"

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm suddenly not able to use the bundled Intellij IDEA git plugin.

In settings I can see this error: `the git process exited with the code 139.

Git is working fine in the editor terminal. My OS is Debian 10.

What can I do to make it work again?

Comment: 139 is a standard exit code to indicate "the program exited because of a Segmetation fault" -- e.g: most porbably a null pointer bug. Does IntelliJ have a console somewhere, where you could see exactly what git commands are executed ? this error may be triggered by a hook rather than by git itself.

Comment: There are logs but I have no idea how I could find the related lines. 
I don't think that it comes from a hook since I never configured once and the bug appeared without any changes related to Git

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: No I use a normal Debian 10 OS (I updated the question)

Comment: OK and your Git version? (assuming the Git plugin depends on the system Git, unless IntelliJ has an embedded Git). Also your IntelliJ version?

Comment: The Git version is 2.20.1 and yes the Git plugin depends on the system Git (path is shown as /usr/bin/git). Intellij version is the last one: 2022.2.4 (I upgraded it to see if I would got rid of the bug)

Comment: I just updated the git version to 2.30.2 and still get the error

Comment: OK. I suppose Git 2.38.1 is not available on Debian?

Comment: Yes you're right (don't know why it updated to this version). Unfortunately 2.38.1 still gives the error

Comment: Would the issue persists if you create a new Debian user account, and un intelliJ from this new account? In other words, is there anything in your 'env' which would be problematic?

Comment: I tried and it works with a new user and a fresh IntelliJ install. Now what should I look in my env please?